# Get only field values instead of documents with TinyDB

Tags: python, python-3.x, tinydb

The following code returning me a list of documents that have the field `text`.

```
db = TinyDB('/stream.json')
Tweet = Query()
db.search(Tweet.text.exists())
```

Instead I want to get only an array of the `text` field values over all the documents that have `text` field. It would be better to get it while reading the json instead of loading everything into the memory and then filtering it.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `TinyDB` only supports query filter. It doesn't support which fields to return in the documents that match that particular query filter, something similar to MongoDB [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find) parameter.

You can always use list comprehension to filter it yourself:

```
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query

db = TinyDB('/stream.json')

Tweet = Query()

texts = [tweet.get('text') for tweet in db.search(Tweet.text.exists())]
print(texts)  # List of all text field values.
```